# Our PowerUser and PowerReader were accidentally deleted. We recreated them but we're still getting errors

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, error, navigation

The user accounts used for our Portal Super User and Portal Super Reader were accidentally deleted in Active Directory.  We recreated them with different names (and re-added them to the user policy for the web application), but now our top navigation and side navigation bars are failing for most of our site collections.  They return with the follow error:

`Error rendering new menu state: The specified user or domain group was not found`

Is there something else that needs to be done for these users besides re-adding them to the user policy for the web application?

This is the error I'm seeing in the logs:

```
Application error when access /_layouts/15/SiteNavigationSettings.aspx, Error=Some or all identity references could not be translated.   

 at System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, Type targetType, Boolean forceSuccess)    

 at System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(Type targetType)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimProviderManager.GetProviderUserKeyClaim(IClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity, SPClaim loginClaim)

System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException: Some or all identity references could not be translated.   
Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The specified user or domain group was not found. ---> System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException: Some or all identity references could not be translated.
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically there are couple steps to configure it

1. you have to add the account into the Policy of Web App
2. you have to run the powershell to configure.
3. Now reset IIS on all servers in the farm.

As a test, run the below powershell to test if new account is configured properly.You should see your new users here.

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication -Identity "<WebApplication>"
$wa.Properties["portalsuperuseraccount"] 
$wa.Properties["portalsuperreaderaccount"]
```

If after above steps, its still throwing the error then you have to clear the config cache on the SharePoint servers.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried all of these and we're still getting that error :(

Comment: are you seeing the new users when you ran the powershell? could you please provide the complete log trace?  did you removed the old accounts from the SharePoint( PWA and if they in managed account) also check if those accounts are in UPA?

Comment: Added the error that I'm getting.